# How to stop ffmpeg m3u8 download if not getting any stream update?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm making a bash script to download m3u8 stream on particular time using crontab.

Sometimes server-sent stream url is invalid or stream stops because server fails to stream.
In both cases, playlist.m3u8 and chunk.m3u8 are both downloadable but stream file pieces in chunk.m3u8 don't update any longer. But ffmpeg keeps downloading "nothing" since chunk.m3u8 file contains any new streams.

Input command:

```
ffmpeg -i 'https://link.to/playlist.m3u8' -c copy -o '~/filename.ts'
```

On abnormal cases:

```
[generic] playlist: Requesting header
[generic] playlist: Downloading m3u8 information
[download] Destination: ~/filename.ts
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-3ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T08:39:03.510Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T09:55:03.510Z')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/anmss0003/nsmu2pe5nj6lx4hhtmsv4fmlbam0a4qelq/1080p_754675733_1591264503510_4560_0_1520.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/anmss0003/nsmu2pe5nj6lx4hhtmsv4fmlbam0a4qelq/1080p_3899144139_1591264506510_4563_0_1521.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/anmss0003/nsmu2pe5nj6lx4hhtmsv4fmlbam0a4qelq/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=34293a1b681e3215730af2d06bd2331c0bf63558842b19103c567c089eb73f39a386cb3a3216e4f841953991fe21c6821af7de68487ee7832b07d8818204ea0d16305d82b0a6e32c815f1544c9b7ae73e8ff4b51b90a3efb7035fb3dabb087e9134cb2e39733138d4f353073864f335e15e0a250c7e3cb61d4aaf83615efe414&_lsu_et_=1591292344':
  Duration: N/A, start: 4560.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:2: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
Output #0, mp4, to 'file:~/filename.ts.part':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[https @ 0xaaaad4f28ae0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/anmss0003/nsmu2pe5nj6lx4hhtmsv4fmlbam0a4qelq/1080p_2058418743_1591264509510_4566_0_1522.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T08:39:03.510Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T09:55:03.510Z')
[https @ 0xaaaad55bfd50] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/anmss0003/nsmu2pe5nj6lx4hhtmsv4fmlbam0a4qelq/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=34293a1b681e3215730af2d06bd2331c0bf63558842b19103c567c089eb73f39a386cb3a3216e4f841953991fe21c6821af7de68487ee7832b07d8818204ea0d16305d82b0a6e32c815f1544c9b7ae73e8ff4b51b90a3efb7035fb3dabb087e9134cb2e39733138d4f353073864f335e15e0a250c7e3cb61d4aaf83615efe414&_lsu_et_=1591292344' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T08:39:03.510Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T09:55:03.510Z')
[https @ 0xaaaad55bfd50] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/anmss0003/nsmu2pe5nj6lx4hhtmsv4fmlbam0a4qelq/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=34293a1b681e3215730af2d06bd2331c0bf63558842b19103c567c089eb73f39a386cb3a3216e4f841953991fe21c6821af7de68487ee7832b07d8818204ea0d16305d82b0a6e32c815f1544c9b7ae73e8ff4b51b90a3efb7035fb3dabb087e9134cb2e39733138d4f353073864f335e15e0a250c7e3cb61d4aaf83615efe414&_lsu_et_=1591292344' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T08:39:03.510Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T09:55:03.510Z')
[https @ 0xaaaad55bfd50] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/anmss0003/nsmu2pe5nj6lx4hhtmsv4fmlbam0a4qelq/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=34293a1b681e3215730af2d06bd2331c0bf63558842b19103c567c089eb73f39a386cb3a3216e4f841953991fe21c6821af7de68487ee7832b07d8818204ea0d16305d82b0a6e32c815f1544c9b7ae73e8ff4b51b90a3efb7035fb3dabb087e9134cb2e39733138d4f353073864f335e15e0a250c7e3cb61d4aaf83615efe414&_lsu_et_=1591292344' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T08:39:03.510Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T09:55:03.510Z')
[https @ 0xaaaad55bfd50] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/anmss0003/nsmu2pe5nj6lx4hhtmsv4fmlbam0a4qelq/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=34293a1b681e3215730af2d06bd2331c0bf63558842b19103c567c089eb73f39a386cb3a3216e4f841953991fe21c6821af7de68487ee7832b07d8818204ea0d16305d82b0a6e32c815f1544c9b7ae73e8ff4b51b90a3efb7035fb3dabb087e9134cb2e39733138d4f353073864f335e15e0a250c7e3cb61d4aaf83615efe414&_lsu_et_=1591292344' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T08:39:03.510Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaad4c595f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T09:55:03.510Z')

...and still goes on until server stops serving playlist.m3u8 file.
```

On normal case:

```
[generic] playlist: Requesting header
[generic] playlist: Downloading m3u8 information
[download] Destination: ~/filename.ts
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-3ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T09:55:34.419Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T10:56:01.419Z')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_2140588392_1591268161419_3627_0_1209.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_1159973342_1591268164419_3630_0_1210.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=31b94f1b48b03755160d6263630248165b873b582123194d369663096e903e691d87ab6c3fb63dfd517e3cf1d320760604ceaed2b168d017061fe4d08822506a7314482b165f2011119469a5c2486518636d7a0eea9dba559babdca7edaf80bb087564aa35bf9df154fc6bb35f54dd397e99a576174fe805da71c8b5cc86feb4&_lsu_et_=1591298832':
  Duration: N/A, start: 3627.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:2: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
Output #0, mp4, to 'file:~/filename.ts.part':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 0
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[https @ 0xaaaadf009ae0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_3958358483_1591268167419_3633_0_1211.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T09:55:34.419Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T10:56:04.419Z')
[https @ 0xaaaadf009ae0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_3853948217_1591268170419_3636_0_1212.ts' for reading
frame=  269 fps= 95 q=-1.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:09.01 bitrate=2792.9kbits/s speed=3.18x    
[https @ 0xaaaadf6e02c0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=31b94f1b48b03755160d6263630248165b873b582123194d369663096e903e691d87ab6c3fb63dfd517e3cf1d320760604ceaed2b168d017061fe4d08822506a7314482b165f2011119469a5c2486518636d7a0eea9dba559babdca7edaf80bb087564aa35bf9df154fc6bb35f54dd397e99a576174fe805da71c8b5cc86feb4&_lsu_et_=1591298832' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T09:55:34.419Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T10:56:07.419Z')
[https @ 0xaaaadf009ae0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_2889557048_1591268173419_3639_0_1213.ts' for reading
frame=  359 fps= 61 q=-1.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:12.01 bitrate=2791.9kbits/s speed=2.04x    
[https @ 0xaaaadf6e02c0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=31b94f1b48b03755160d6263630248165b873b582123194d369663096e903e691d87ab6c3fb63dfd517e3cf1d320760604ceaed2b168d017061fe4d08822506a7314482b165f2011119469a5c2486518636d7a0eea9dba559babdca7edaf80bb087564aa35bf9df154fc6bb35f54dd397e99a576174fe805da71c8b5cc86feb4&_lsu_et_=1591298832' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T09:55:34.419Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T10:56:10.419Z')
[https @ 0xaaaadf009ae0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_3485591329_1591268176419_3642_0_1214.ts' for reading
frame=  449 fps= 50 q=-1.0 size=    5120kB time=00:00:15.00 bitrate=2795.2kbits/s speed=1.67x    
[https @ 0xaaaadf6e02c0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=31b94f1b48b03755160d6263630248165b873b582123194d369663096e903e691d87ab6c3fb63dfd517e3cf1d320760604ceaed2b168d017061fe4d08822506a7314482b165f2011119469a5c2486518636d7a0eea9dba559babdca7edaf80bb087564aa35bf9df154fc6bb35f54dd397e99a576174fe805da71c8b5cc86feb4&_lsu_et_=1591298832' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T09:55:34.419Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T10:56:13.419Z')
[https @ 0xaaaadf009ae0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_2256435886_1591268179419_3645_0_1215.ts' for reading
frame=  539 fps= 45 q=-1.0 size=    6144kB time=00:00:18.01 bitrate=2794.2kbits/s speed= 1.5x    
[https @ 0xaaaadf6e02c0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=31b94f1b48b03755160d6263630248165b873b582123194d369663096e903e691d87ab6c3fb63dfd517e3cf1d320760604ceaed2b168d017061fe4d08822506a7314482b165f2011119469a5c2486518636d7a0eea9dba559babdca7edaf80bb087564aa35bf9df154fc6bb35f54dd397e99a576174fe805da71c8b5cc86feb4&_lsu_et_=1591298832' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T09:55:34.419Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T10:56:16.419Z')
[https @ 0xaaaadf009ae0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_1520430104_1591268182419_3648_0_1216.ts' for reading
frame=  629 fps= 42 q=-1.0 size=    7168kB time=00:00:21.02 bitrate=2793.4kbits/s speed=1.39x    
[https @ 0xaaaadf6e02c0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=31b94f1b48b03755160d6263630248165b873b582123194d369663096e903e691d87ab6c3fb63dfd517e3cf1d320760604ceaed2b168d017061fe4d08822506a7314482b165f2011119469a5c2486518636d7a0eea9dba559babdca7edaf80bb087564aa35bf9df154fc6bb35f54dd397e99a576174fe805da71c8b5cc86feb4&_lsu_et_=1591298832' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T09:55:34.419Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T10:56:22.419Z')
[https @ 0xaaaadf009ae0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_2229049379_1591268185419_3651_0_1217.ts' for reading
[https @ 0xaaaadf02f510] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_2659945939_1591268188419_3654_0_1218.ts' for reading
frame=  719 fps= 40 q=-1.0 size=    8192kB time=00:00:24.00 bitrate=2795.3kbits/s speed=1.32x    
[https @ 0xaaaadf6e02c0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=31b94f1b48b03755160d6263630248165b873b582123194d369663096e903e691d87ab6c3fb63dfd517e3cf1d320760604ceaed2b168d017061fe4d08822506a7314482b165f2011119469a5c2486518636d7a0eea9dba559babdca7edaf80bb087564aa35bf9df154fc6bb35f54dd397e99a576174fe805da71c8b5cc86feb4&_lsu_et_=1591298832' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T09:55:34.419Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T10:56:22.419Z')
[https @ 0xaaaadf6e02c0] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/chunklist_1080p.m3u8?_lsu_sa_=31b94f1b48b03755160d6263630248165b873b582123194d369663096e903e691d87ab6c3fb63dfd517e3cf1d320760604ceaed2b168d017061fe4d08822506a7314482b165f2011119469a5c2486518636d7a0eea9dba559babdca7edaf80bb087564aa35bf9df154fc6bb35f54dd397e99a576174fe805da71c8b5cc86feb4&_lsu_et_=1591298832' for reading
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="nmss-daterange",START-DATE="2020-06-04T09:55:34.419Z"')
[hls @ 0xaaaaded3a5f0] Skip ('#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-06-04T10:56:25.419Z')
[https @ 0xaaaadf02f510] Opening 'https://now-livecloud.pstatic.net/lip2_kr/cnmss0003/hbt6zn63jhkvtx8exbddrfrlbc8ioxe4ux/1080p_4119016691_1591268191419_3657_0_1219.ts' for reading
frame=  899 fps= 40 q=-1.0 size=   10240kB time=00:00:30.00 bitrate=2796.0kbits/s speed=1.32x

...and still goes on until server stops serving playlist.m3u8 file.
```

So, how can I make ffmpeg to stop when there's update no more on chunk.m3u8 file after some tries?

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg -max_reload 1 -i 'https://link.to/playlist.m3u8' -c copy -o '~/filename.ts'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).